# Regex for multiple words separated by spaces or commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create regex for multiple strings separated by comma or space.

```
Lorem Ipsum // valid
Lorem, Ipsum //valid
Lorem, Ipsum, Ipsum, Ipsum // multiple valid
Lorem // invalid without space/comma
```

Here is what i have so far:

```
^\w+(,\s*\w+){3}$/
```

Comment: So they must have a space but optionally a comma? Or are comma separated values (with no space) also valid such as `Lorem,Ipsum`? Also, is `Lorem ,Ipsum` valid? On that note, are `Lorem, , Ipsum`, `Lorem,, Ipsum` or `Lorem  Ipsum` valid? Basically, what are your exact requirements/conditions?

Comment: Single words are accepted. If there is anything else after word example "Test" space or comma than it should be not accepted

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: Are you looking for `\w+(?:[, ]+\w+)+`?

Comment: Try [`^\w+(?:(?:,\s\w+)+|(?:\s\w+)+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/72K30X/1) - it will match a string that starts with 1+ word chars, and then has 1 or more repetitions of `,` followed with a whitespace and 1+ word chars *or* 1+ repetitions of a space followed with 1+ word chars. Another way of writing it is [`^\w+(?=(,?\s))(?:\1\w+)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/dAgw2b/1)

Comment: Once you coma back, please consider accepting the answer that worked best for you.

Answer (score 9):

You may use

```
^\w+(?:(?:,\s\w+)+|(?:\s\w+)+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/72K30X/1).

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?:` - start of an alternation group:

  - `(?:,\s\w+)+` - `,`, whitespace, 1+ word chars
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:\s\w+)+` - whitespace and then 1+ word chars
- `)` - end of group
- `$` - end of string.

You may shorten the pattern using a lookahead and a capturing group:

```
^\w+(?=(,?\s))(?:\1\w+)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dAgw2b/1). Here, the difference is `(?=(,?\s))(?:\1\w+)+`:

- `(?=(,?\s))` - a positive lookahead that checks if there is an optional `,` and then a whitespace immediately to the right of the current location and captures that sequence into Group 1
- `(?:\1\w+)+` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `\1` - the same text captured into Group 1
  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dAgw2b/1).

Comment: Nice efforts for explaining all the granularities +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
^(\w+[, ]+)*\w+$
```

Comment: Although this may answer the questions, you may wan't to provide some extra details and explain the answer. In it's current state this answer is low-quality.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to match the whole phrase:

```
^(\w+(,|\s)\s*)+\w+$
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the above worked for me, I came up with this:

```
/([^,\s]+)/g
```